# OpenMP Multithread Parallel Programming

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

My parallel program have same time compared to serial program and I don't know why (both 7.3s for small data 43s for big data, so there is no acceleration). But I guess it caused of printf? But my teacher ask me keep to use printf.
And 1 more, is there a way to parallel the input procedure? Because it also takes much time. (With some trick like delete the number after read, etc xD)

```
void input(int ***a, int set){
 int i,j;
 FILE *f;
switch(set){
    case 1: f = fopen("dataset1.txt","r");break;
    case 2: f = fopen("dataset2.txt","r");break;
    case 3: f = fopen("dataset3.txt","r");break;
    case 4: f = fopen("dataset4.txt","r");break;
    case 5: f = fopen("dataset5.txt","r");break;
    case 6: f = fopen("dataset6.txt","r");break;
    case 7: f = fopen("dataset7.txt","r");break;
    case 8: f = fopen("dataset8.txt","r");break;
    case 9: f = fopen("dataset9.txt","r");break;
    case 10: f = fopen("dataset10.txt","r");break;
}
for(i=0;i<s;i++)
    for(j=0;j<s;j++)
        fscanf(f,"%d ",&(*a)[i][j]);
fclose(f);
}

serial code:
    void rangeCheck(int **a){
      int i,j;
      for(i=0;i<s;i++)
        for(j=0;j<s;j++)
         if(a[i][j]>=min && a[i][j]<=max)
           printf("(%d,%d) ",i,j);
    }

parallel code:
    void rangeCheck(const int **a){
      int i,chunk,id,p=4;
      chunk = (s%p==0) ? s/p : s/p+1;
      #pragma omp parallel private(i,id)
      {
        id = omp_get_thread_num();
        #pragma omp for schedule (static,chunk)
          for(i=0;i<s;i++){
            int j;
            for(j=0;j<s;j++)
              if(a[i][j]>=min && a[i][j]<=max)
                printf("(%d,%d) ",i,j);
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: printf can slow it down very much if you print lots of data. Remove the printf and instead increment a counter to count the number of items that would have been printed. Then print value of the counter after the loops finished. Does this make it faster?

Comment: How do you measure the time? Does it include the input time?